# jquery change firing when binding knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

If I have my model

```
function SearchModel() {
        this.SearchCriteria = "";        
    }
```

and within my code have:

```
model.SearchCriteria = data;

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

and then in my html:

```
 <select id="vehiclesMake" data-bind="options: SearchCriteria.Tool.VehicleMakes, optionsText: 'Description', value: SearchCriteria.Tool.SelectedModel, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

all of which works fine. My dropdown gets populated as expected.

Now the problem I am having is when I add:

```
$('#vehiclesMake').change(function () {            
      loadSearchTool();                            
  });
```

where loadSearchTool() does:

```
loadSearchTool = function () {
        var postCode = $('#postcode').val();
        var distance = $('#distance').val();
        var make = $('#vehiclesMake').val();
        var makemodel = $('#makemodel').val();
        var minPrice = $('#minPrice').val();
        var maxPrice = $('#maxPrice').val();

        data.getQuickSearch(postCode, distance, make, makemodel, minPrice, maxPrice, function (data) {
            //our success function                
            console.log(data.Result);           
            if (data.Result == 'Fail') {
                console.log('Fail');//TO DO
            }
            else {
                model.SearchCriteria = data;

                ko.applyBindings(model);
            }

        }, function () {            
            console.log('error');//TO DO
        });
    };
```

With all the code above, when loadsearchtool(whichis also called on pageload) binds to the dropdown, the .change() code is firing and I end up in an infinite loop.

How can I get around this? This is my first crack at knockoutjs so am a bit of a newbie with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to move `ko.applyBindings(model);` outside `loadSearchTool()`. ko.applyBindings should only be called once (from `$(document).ready()` for example).

You probably also want to change SearchCriteria to an observable:

```
this.SearchCriteria = ko.observable("");
```

To update the data use:

```
model.SearchCriteria(data);
```

Comment: OK that seems to have stopped the problem. Thanks for that.